# Como fundir várias tabelas Excel numa só?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

Tenho 3000 tabelas como neste exemplo:

[image: txt sheet]

Preciso-las fundir numa só e estou a usar o comando:

```
=ÍNDICE(TXT!$B$1:$B$200,CORRESP(MAIOR(SE(TXT!$A$1:$A$200="Last Name:",TXT!$B$1:$B$200,""),1),TXT!$B$1:$B$200,0))
```

O problema é que apenas me apresenta o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será este comando o mais indicado para este caso? Se sim o que estou a fazer mal?

PS: Apenas necessito dos dados assinalados em csv sheet

Answer (score 0):

Se os intervalos são regulares, você pode fazer o seguinte:
Crie uma coluna auxiliar na aba CSV com título "linha" em `A2`

em `A3` preencha com o número 8, que é a primeira linha do card da aba TXT

em `A4` preencha com `=A3+15`

a fórmula da célula 'B3' ficará `=índice(txt!$b:$b;$A3;1)`

a fórmula da célula 'C3' ficará `=índice(txt!$b:$b;$A3+1;1)`

a fórmula da célula 'D3' ficará `=índice(txt!$b:$b;$A3+2;1)`

E assim por diante...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, resolveu a minha questão